# Run JavaScript function on page load as well as on setInterval

Tags: javascript, ajax

My current script

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"query.php?currency=<?=$currencycode;?>"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#value").attr("value", data).attr("size", data.length - 2);
    });
},3000);
```

My webpage is only query the php file every 3 seconds but I want to make it query when the page is open and then to execute the loop refreshing the value for my input every 3 seconds. Now you have to wait 3 seconds untill the value is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the function from the `setInterval()` method and change the anonymous function to a named function.

Now all you have to do is invoke the function on page load as well as in `setInterval()` by just referencing the function name like this:

```
function someFunc() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"query.php?currency=<?=$currencycode;?>"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#value").attr("value", data).attr("size", data.length - 2);
    });
}

someFunc(); // function will invoke on page load

setInterval(someFunc, 3000); // function will invoke after every 3 seconds
```

---

Check and run the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
function someFunc() {
  console.log("yes")
}

someFunc();
setInterval(someFunc, 3000);
```

Comment: Is working, looks much cleaner and easier for me. I have no experience with javascript.